# Why anchors have different behavior when changing iframe heights?

Tags: html, iframe

Help understand the next moment.

There is a page that connects via iframe on another page. Suppose that the layout of the connected page (iframe.html) has the following form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>iFrame</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .inner__block {
            width: 100%;
            background: #f1f1b4;
            height: 100px;
            border-bottom: 3px solid black;
        }

        .test__block {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            background: #eceb51;
            border-bottom: 3px solid black;
        }

        h3 {
            margin-top: 0;
            padding-top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="inner__block">
        Very big iframe
        <br>
        <a href="#test">#test</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#test1">#test1</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#test2">#test2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="test" class="test__block">
        <h3>TEST</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="test1" class="test__block">
        <h3>TEST 1</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="test2" class="test__block">
        <h3>TEST 2</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="test3" class="test__block">
        <h3>TEST 3</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page where the iframe is located has the following layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style>
        .iframe {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2131px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <div>
        <iframe class="iframe" src="iframe.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In such a scenario, following by anchors in an iframe do not work.

But if you reduce the height of the iframe in styles by half, then the anchors begin to work as they should.

Why such a different behavior of anchors depending on the height of the iframe?

Comment: Right-click on the link and click inspect. You will likely see something is overlaying the link in one resolution and not in another

Comment: @mplungjan, nothing is overlaying on the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely normal. And the browser can't know, what you are trying to achieve.

An iframe is a document of it's own with a separate scrollable HTML. Your iframe is so high that the content of the iframe is fully shown, thus not scrollbars (apart from your `scrolling="no"`).

This will be more clear if you change the height of the iframe to something smaller—say 800 pixels—and allow scrolling of the iframe. Then you will see, that the iframe itself is scrolled. See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/eec95c1023a9933c579221e7a37b66dc) for a demonstration

The outer window thus has no insight into the inner one.

What you can do is listen to click events, look if a target is involved, send a [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) from the iframe to the container window with the position of the loink target and then decide, if the container window should be scrolled

David Bradshaw has a solution: [iFrame Resizer V4](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)
This can resize the frame automatically and makes the scrolls work as you like.

For the library to work you need to add this to the iframe.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@4.1.1/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

and this to the container.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@4.1.1/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
<script>
// init the iframes to work with iframeresizer
iFrameResize({inPageLinks: true},
  ".iframe" // this is the selector for the iframes to work like this
);
</script>
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/eec95c1023a9933c579221e7a37b66dc?editors=1111
(This is the iframe pen: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/85643c47de49983ca67c8898f74ef4fb?editors=1100)

Comment: @DavertTanz I added a link to a library which can help you

Comment: @DavidTanz I added an example to my answer

Comment: I looked at the library - it is similarly based on postMessage() to follow anchors. It really can help me. Thanks a lot for your help!